# Get the values of All checkboxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, checkbox

When a button is clicked a new category is added to the database and also displayed on the same page as well.But my problem is that when I click multiple times on button it adds multiple checkboxes for same checkbox value. I made it to insert into database only if it is not already present. My issue is that when i click on button it should add the category if it not present in database. I have two function

1. add_cat(); javascript function which calls ajax for adding the new category to the database.
2. is php function which is used for creating new page.

I did that when displaying checkboxes on page i used name= cats[] like array for all checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cats[]" id="<?php echo $row{'term_id'};?>" value="<?php echo $row{'name'};?>"> <?php echo $row{'name'}; ?> `
```

In add_cat() function i am using this code

```
var val = document.getElementById('cat_name').value;
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('cats');
var flag = 0;
for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i] == val) {
        flag = 1;
    }
    alert(flag);
} //check the duplicates
if (flag == 1) {
    alert(flag);
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Already exists";
    setTimeout(function() { // to show the Error
        $('#error').fadeIn("fast").delay(500).fadeOut("slow");
    }, 1500);
    flag = 0;
} else {
    var div = document.getElementById('divContainer');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<input id='chk_" + idCounter + "' type='checkbox' checked value='" + val + "' /><label for='chk_" + idCounter + "'>" + val + "</label>";
    idCounter++;
    cat_2_db(val); // call ajax to insert  category in database
}
```

But problem is that flag never get turned into 1 and checkboxes variable is not returning checkbox values

Comment: -1 Very poor quality. Please reformat your question and make it **readable** ...

Comment: ok @ cept0i m doing kindly don't downgrade my reputation already i have very less

Comment: you ok i mean to reputaion is  we are limited to use stack function that is why only and getting more -ive it denieds to post the next qn

Comment: you should be as neat as possible and as short as possible to clearly explain your problem then no one will give down vote...i indented your code accept it

Comment: [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @shusheel alright i will do the same that time i was posted the qn i see that qn is meshed i was just editing it in between i got a down vote but finally i need solution

Comment: are you trying to load input checkbox from database and you are button which when clicked adds a row to database but what is that row and where are you getting the data to populate in database ?

Comment: can you show you database schema and when you click on button you need some values to post to database right ?

Comment: click button dds new checkbox category without load this click performs two tasks 1. adds into database 2. it shows the same thing on that page where button is clicked

Comment: <?php include_once('connection.php');?>
<?php $name =$_GET['cat_name']; echo $val;?>
<?php
$checkCatID = mysql_query("SELECT name from terms WHERE name = '$name'");
if (mysql_num_rows($checkCatID)!=false){}
else{
 $query = "INSERT INTO terms VALUES('','$name','$name')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to create account: ".mysql_error());
}
?>
 called when add_2_db function is called

Comment: so you want to retain the checkboxes on page refresh so adding it to database ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52432/discussion-between-susheel-and-monika)

Comment: i don't understand what u want to say but onclick my check value is added to the database without page refreshing

Comment: `if (checkboxes[i].value == val) {` check for value

Comment: Learn how to ask. Don't even try to ask people not to downvote your question. Learn to format your question. Make your words simple. Don't give me a change to format your question. __Reputation will go up and go down.__ Don't try to stop people from downvoting, or try to downvote somebody's question for revenge (although you couldn't;). That's serial downvoting.

Comment: ok al right i have  no time for revenge and  i always upvote the answer white i found it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to find the value:

```
if (checkboxes[i].value === val) {
```

Refactoring your for loop

```
for(var i = 0, i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].value === val) {
        flag = 1;
    }
}
```